# how to find namespace for an existing instance of a class

Tags: php, magento, instantiation, instance-variables

In this example, the platform used is Magento, but I believe this is a generic question related to Object Oriented Programming.

When a page or API URL is called, the first class to be instantiated will then instantiate other classes, and so forth.  I need to change a setting in an instance of one class (there will only be one instance) from within another class.

For example, I am working in class `Praxis_Rest_ProductsController::getAction()` and want to do this:

```
(existing instance of Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)->setDebug(true);
```

I know for sure that the connection class is `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` and that this is instantiated already, and only once.

How do I do this?  Is this possible?

-- EDIT --
@Andrej Ludinovskov below posted a great solution if I *know* the object name, but in my case, I'm in a spot in the coding which has no relationship too it.  In fact it might be 7-10 different classes in the stack downstream where that instantiated object is called; but I do know that class was instantiated and only once for that matter.  In this case I'm trying to find $object when all I know is that it's an instance of `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this simple if or I miss something:

```
if ($object instanceof Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql) {
    $object->setDebug(true);
}
```

Comment: No (though this is a good idea for other cases), it's just the opposite - I don't `know` the namespace of `$object`.  I'm trying to do this: `(instanceof Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)->setDebug(true);`

Comment: @OliverWilliams Well, I'm confused what you want to get. Do you have object or not or you want to check $this?